# Why is Rails reading old database values?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, amazon-web-services

If I update a record manually through MySQL workbench, on the corresponding site it takes multiple page refreshes to get the updated record, but if I reload the record from MySQL workbench the update is there. I have no cache setup on the application server.

What could possibly be causing this? I can't think of anything else to check. Could it be some kind of pooling issue?

Answer (score 1):

That made for avoid touching database each time you accessing attributes.
You can call `reload` method for synchronize object data.

```
user = User.first
# at this moment object changed from outside
user.reload
```

Comment: I see what you mean but it's still doing it after a hard refresh of the page after the value has been changed. I increased my connection pool from 5 to 10 and it seems to have stopped occurring. I wish I could find better documentation on MySQL pooling and passenger worker configuration.